# Python statsmodels seasonal_decompose() Trend is a mirror of the original data

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I'm trying to perform seasonal decomposition on a set of data but I'm a little confused about the results.

As seen below there is no seasonality or residual and the trend is just the original series. Is this telling me there is no trend, seasonality or residual?

```
data = pd.read_csv('D:\OneDrive\OneDrive Documents\data.csv', index_col='Month', parse_dates=True)
result = seasonal_decompose(data['Volume'], model='additive', freq=1)
result.plot();
```

`seasonal_decompose` results:

[image]

Comment: `freq` should be the length of a cycle, e.g. 12 for monthly data and annual cycle.